# JavaFX TableView: copy text as rendered in cell

Tags: javafx

I want to implement copy functionality in a TableView. The text to be copied should be the actual text that is rendered in the cell, not the .toString version of the data model to be rendered, that is, it should be the .getText of the cell.

There are several ways of getting the data from a cell. However to get the rendered cell text contents, the procedure seems to be like this:

- Get the cell data.
- Get the cell factory.
- Use the factory to create a cell.
- Use the cell's `updateItem` method to render the data, then `getText` to get the rendered text.

The last step is not possible due to `updateItem` being protected.

*How can I access the rendered text of any given cell in a TableView?*

Comment: In general you can't, and that's by design. JavaFX controls are based on the MVC architecture, in which the view (e.g. the cell) observes the data (in the model): the view does not contain the data. If you want the rendered text to be available externally to the view, then the rendered text essentially becomes part of the model. So either you can introduce properties in the model class that are used both by your cell implementation and your copy functionality, or you can write the formatting code elsewhere and access it both from the cell and the copy functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, although I disagree about the design. I don't see a good reason why there shouldn't be API available to read out the contents of the view. Anyway, I've solved it by subclassing Cell.

Comment: The problem is that you'll be forced to create cells for every item in order to do that. Cells are UI components and are typically much more expensive to create than the data: remember that most of the time, most items do not have cells associated with them. So if you have a very large table, using the cells to get the data you want to copy will be prohibitively expensive. If you factor the "format text for cell" functionality out of the cell, you don't have that performance issue.

Comment: Yes, performance is a good point.

Answer (score 3):

The process you outline involves getting the text (i.e. data) from the view (the cell), which violates the principles behind the MVC/MVP design. From a practical perspective, it involves creating UI elements (which are expensive to create) to essentially manipulate data (which is typically much less expensive to create and process). Additionally, depending on exactly what you're doing, the UI elements may impose additional threading constraints on your code (as they are essentially single-threaded).

If you need to use the "formatting text" functionality outside of the cell, you should factor it out elsewhere and reuse it in both the "copy" functionality you need and in the cell. At a minimum, this could be done by making the "format text" functionality part of the cell factory:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FormattingTableCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {

    private final Function<T, String> formatter ;

    public FormattingTableCellFactory(Function<T, String> formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter ;
    }

    public FormattingTableCellFactory() {
        this(T::toString);
    }

    public final Function<T, String> getFormatter() {
        return formatter ;
    }

    @Override
    public TableCell<S,T> call(TableColumn<S,T> col) {
        return new TableCell<S,T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(item == null ? null : formatter.apply(item));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

(Obviously you could extend this to produce more sophisticated cells with graphical content, etc.)

And now your copy functionality can simply apply the formatter to the data, without reference to any actual cells. Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private String copy(TableView<Product> table) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Product p : table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TableColumn<Product, ?> column : table.getColumns()) {
                Function<Object, String> formatter = ((FormattingTableCellFactory) column.getCellFactory()).getFormatter();
                data.add(formatter.apply(column.getCellObservableValue(p).getValue()));
            }
            sb.append(String.join("\t", data)).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString() ;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Product> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        table.getColumns().add(column("Product", Product::nameProperty, String::toString));
        NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Price", Product::priceProperty, currencyFormat::format));

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Product("Product "+i, rng.nextDouble()*100));
        }

        Button copy = new Button("Copy");
        copy.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(copy(table)));
        copy.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(copy, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(copy, new Insets(10));
        root.setBottom(copy);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S,ObservableValue<T>> property, Function<T,String> formatter) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setCellFactory(new FormattingTableCellFactory<>(formatter));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Product {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty() ;

        public Product(String name, double price) {
            setName(name);
            setPrice(price);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
            return this.price;
        }


        public final double getPrice() {
            return this.priceProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setPrice(final double price) {
            this.priceProperty().set(price);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can get rid of the less typesafe code at the expense of less flexibility:

```
private final Function<String, String> defaultFormatter = Function.identity() ;
private final Function<Number, String> priceFormatter = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance()::format  ;

private String copy(TableView<Product> table) {
    return table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream().map(product -> 
        String.format("%s\t%s", 
                defaultFormatter.apply(product.getName()),
                priceFormatter.apply(product.getPrice()))
    ).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

and

```
    table.getColumns().add(column("Product", Product::nameProperty, defaultFormatter));
    table.getColumns().add(column("Price", Product::priceProperty, priceFormatter));
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'll look into it.

Comment: Updated with example.